# кнопка Exit завершает приложение на втором клике, почему?

Tags: javafx

Написано маленькое приложение которое должно закрываться после нажатия на кнопку **Exit**, в принципе это реализовать мне удалось, НО выход их приложения происходит после второго клика на кнопку.

Объясните пожалуйста почему так происходит? И как сделать чтобы выход выполнялся после первого нажатия?

```
public class Controller {

      @FXML
      private Button buttonExit;

      public Controller() {
      }


      public void buttonExitClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        buttonExit.setOnAction(event -> Platform.exit());
      }
}
```

код кнопки в интерфейсе

```
<Button fx:id="buttonExit" onAction="#buttonExitClick"  .... text="Exit" ....>
```

Пробовал смотреть дебагом, получается после первого нажатия на кнопку событие попадает в **buttonExit.setOnAction** и только после второго клика уже попадает в **event -> Platform.exit()** после чего собственно и происходит выход из приложения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод который вызывается по нажатию на кнопку у вас описан в **fxml**. Но в нем вместо действия, вы еще раз добавляете слушатель. Вам надо убрать добавление слушателя, но оставить само действие.

Просто замените код

```
public void buttonExitClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    buttonExit.setOnAction(event -> Platform.exit());
}
```

На

```
public void buttonExitClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    Platform.exit();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, интуитивно чувствовал что что-то срабатывает 2 раза, но не мог въехать что именно и как. Все заработало.